# shellsort algorithm isn't working

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I wanted to implement shellsort myself instead of copy pasting the ones online, I would appreciate if anyone could help me find the mistake and improve my silly lil code I will put down my code down below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void swap(int p, int j, int *arr);
void shellSort(int arr[], int gap, int size);

int main() {
    int array[] = {12, 2, 4, 23, 5, 1, 6, 8, 16, 64, 32, 7, 43, 243, 76};
    int size = 15;
    for (int i = 15; i >= 1; i /= 2) {
        shellSort(array,i,size);
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    print(array, 15);
    // shellSortwhile(array, 15);
    print(array, 15);
}

void shellSort(int arr[], int gap, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += gap) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + gap]) {
            swap(i, i + gap, arr);
            for(int j = i; j >= 0; j -= gap) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[j - gap]) {
                    swap(j-gap, j, arr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Now the array will be printed
2
4
5
6
7
7
8
1076814756
12
15
16
23
32
43
64
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading/writing out of bounds. `i+gap` is 15 in your first iteration. You have only 15 elements in your array, so you are reading one past the last element. This is the most common mistake in C, don't feel bad about it!

Comment: hi, thanks so much yuh its a really mistake I just realized my brain isn't working haha, but after I fixed it my result is still faulty

Comment: Now the array will be printed
1
2
4
5
1076814756
6
7
7
8
12
16
23
32
43
64
this is the output sorry last one got entered by mistake

Comment: hi I just realized I am using 15 just to find gap, I am not using to access my array so it should not be out of bound

Comment: The `1076814756` clearly indicates that you are reading out of bounds somewhere. If you changed your code but it's still happening, update your question with the updated code. I recommend that you simulate the algorithm in your head, step by step, see if you ever index with a value >= 15. Or you run it in the debugger, same thing, paying attention to each time you index.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void swap(int p, int j, int* arr );
void shellSortwhile(int arr[], int size);
void shellSort(int arr[], int gap,int size);
void print(int* arr, int size);
int main() {
    int array[]={12,2,4,23,5,1,6,8,16,64,32,7,43,243,76};
    int size=15;
    for (int i=size/2;i>=1;i/=2)#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void swap(int p, int j, int* arr );
void shellSortwhile(int arr[], int size);
void shellSort(int arr[], int gap,int size);
void print(int* arr, int size);
int main() {
    int array[]={12,2,4,23,5,1,6,8,16,64,32,7,43,243,76};
    int size=15;
    print(array,15);
    for (int i=size/2;i>=1;i/=2)
   { shellSort(array,i,size);
    cout<<i<<endl;

   }
    print(array,15);
   // shellSortwhile(array,15);

}
void print(int* arr, int size)
{
    cout<<"Now the array will be printed"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
void swap(int p, int j, int* arr )
{
    int temp=arr[p];
    arr[p]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=temp;
}
void shellSortwhile(int arr[], int size) {
    int i, j, gap, temp;
    gap = size/2;

    while(gap > 0) {
        i = gap;

        while(i < size) {
            temp = arr[i];

for(j = i; (j >= gap) && (arr[j - gap] > temp); j -=gap) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
        }
        gap = gap / 2;
    }
}


void shellSort(int arr[], int gap,int size)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size-(gap);i++)

    {
    if (arr[i]>arr[i+gap])
    {
        swap(i,i+gap,arr);

        for(int j=i;j>=0+gap;j-=gap)
        {if (arr[j]<arr[j-gap])
            swap(j-gap,j,arr);
        }
    }
    }
}
   { shellSort(array,i,size);
    cout<<i<<endl;

   }
    print(array,15);
   // shellSortwhile(array,15);
        print(array,15);

}
void print(int* arr, int size)
{
    cout<<"Now the array will be printed"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
void swap(int p, int j, int* arr )
{
    int temp=arr[p];
    arr[p]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=temp;
}
void shellSortwhile(int arr[], int size) {
    int i, j, gap, temp;
    gap = size/2;

    while(gap > 0) {
        i = gap;

        while(i < size) {
            temp = arr[i];

for(j = i; (j >= gap) && (arr[j - gap] > temp); j -=gap) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
        }
        gap = gap / 2;
    }
}


void shellSort(int arr[], int gap,int size)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size-(gap);i++)

    {
    if (arr[i]>arr[i+gap])
    {
        swap(i,i+gap,arr);
        print(arr,size);

        for(int j=i;j>=0+gap;j-=gap)
        {if (arr[j]<arr[j-gap])
            swap(j-gap,j,arr);
             print(arr,size);
        }
    }
    }
}
```